# Paint the tree with the following design

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, trees

I know that is better to report some code to help the community to understand what is my problem, but I need to reproduce the following Figure, with the array reported below

[image]

I want refactoring my actual result with this figure in my latex document

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcounter{nodeidx}
\newcounter{example}
\setcounter{nodeidx}{1}

\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,
    arrows.meta,
    %shapes.multipart,
    %arrows
}

\newcommand{\nodes}[1]{%
    \foreach \num [count=\n starting from 0] in {#1}{% no need for an external counter
      \node[minimum size=6mm, draw, rectangle] (n\n) at (\n,0) {\num};
    }
}
\newcommand{\brckt}[4][1]{% [ lvl ] { from, to, text }
    \coordinate (left) at ($(n#2.south west)+(-2mm,-1mm)$);
    \coordinate (right) at ($(n#3.south east)+(2mm,-1mm)$);
    \draw (left) -- ($(left)+(0,-1mm*#1)$) --node[below,midway,font=\scriptsize] {#4} ($(right)+(0,-1mm*#1)$) -- (right);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %\pgftransparencygroup
        \nodes{2, 4, 3, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 7}
        %\endpgftransparencygroup
        %\pgftransparencygroup
        \brckt[2]{0}{5}{Query(0, 5)}
        %\endpgftransparencygroup
        %\pgftransparencygroup
        \brckt{3}{9}{~~~~~~~Query(3, 9)}% used ~ to push the label
        %\endpgftransparencygroup
        \brckt[2]{8}{9}{Query(8, 9)}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Original Array where perform the RMQ.}
    \label{fig:origianl_array}
  \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
        for tree = {
            rectangle split,
            rectangle split horizontal,
            rectangle split parts=10,
            rectangle split ignore empty parts,
            draw,
            %
            parent anchor=south,
            child  anchor=north,
            calign=edge midpoint,
            edge = {-Stealth, semithick},
            l sep=6mm,
            where level=0{s sep=11mm}{s sep=3mm},
                    }
        [2 \nodepart{two} 4 \nodepart{three} 3 \nodepart{four} 1 \nodepart{five} 6
          \nodepart{six} 7 \nodepart{seven} 8 \nodepart{eight} 9 \nodepart{nine} 1 \nodepart{ten}  7, color={red}
            [2\nodepart{two} 2 \nodepart{two} 4 \nodepart{three} 3 \nodepart{four} 1 \nodepart{five} 6
               [2\nodepart{two} 4
                   [2] [4]]
               [3\nodepart{two} 1 \nodepart{three} 6
               [3] [1 \nodepart{two} 6
                       [1] [6]
               ]]
            ]
            [7 \nodepart{two} 8 \nodepart{three} 9 \nodepart{four} 1
              \nodepart{six} 7,fit=band, color={red}
               [7 \nodepart{two} 8
                    [7]
                    [8]
               ]
               [9\nodepart{two} 1 \nodepart{three} 7, color={red}
                    [9]
                    [1\nodepart{two} 7, color={red}
                        [10, color={green}]
                        [7]
                    ]
               ]
            ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    \caption{Update the value in position 8 with value 10}
    \label{fig:update_rmq}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

With this result

[image]

Comment: What you try so far? Given MWE is not related to desired tree at all.

Comment: I have no idea how to join the two figure and make one single figure, what I found it inside the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your MWE is misleading (copy of some not related tree), to help you one need to write code from scratch.
- only as starting point, so code is quite rudimentariness
- missed label I left to you (you can add them on the same way as where I rewrote them)

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    circle, draw, fill=gray!30,
    minimum size=1.5em, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
/tikz/every label/.style = {font=\tiny},
/tikz/FIT/.style = {draw, very thick, rounded corners, fill=gray!30,
                    inner sep=4pt, inner ysep=8pt, yshift=-4pt,
                    fit=#1},
% tree
/tikz/every edge/.style={draw=gray, -Straight Barb, 
                         -Straight Barb, shorten >=3pt, shorten <=3pt,
                         bend angle = 15},% style for bended arrows
    edge=semithick,
    l sep=4mm,
    s sep=12mm,
    where level=3{l sep=11mm}{},% at level 3 increase l sep
    where level=4{no edge, very thick, fill=white}{},
            }% level 4 is the lowest
[11, label=below:{1:[0,7]},  name=t0
    [13, label=below:{2:[0,3]},  name=t11
        [17, label=below:{4:[0,1]},  name=t21
            [18, thick, label=below:{8:[0,0]}
                [18, label=below:0]
            ]
            [17, draw=none, fill=gray,thick, label=below:{9:[1,1]},  name=t31
                [17, label=below:1, name=n1]
            ]
        ]
        [13, draw=none,fill=gray, label=below:{5:[2,3]}
            [13, very thick, label=below:{10:[2,2]}
                [13, draw=none, fill=gray, label=below:2]
            ]
            [19, very thick, label=below:{11:[3,3]}
                [19, label=below:3, name=n3]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [11, very thick,edge=thick, label=below:{3:[4,7]}
        [11, thick,edge=thick,
            [15, thick,edge=thick,
                [15, label=below:4]
            ]
            [11, very thick,edge=thick,
                [13, label=below:5]
            ]
        ]
        [20, very thick,edge=thick,
            [20, very thick,edge=thick,
                [13, label=below:6]
            ]
            [99, very thick,edge=thick,,
                [13, label=below:7]
            ]
        ]
     ]
]
\scoped[on background layer]
\node[FIT=(n1) (n3)] {};
\draw
    (t0)  edge [bend right] (t11)
    (t11) edge [bend right] (t21)
    (t21) edge [bend  left] (t31);
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

For adding bended arrows, you need to add names to nodes between which you like to draw them and define style for those arrows. (added to above MWE).  After this additions, tree diagram is:

[image]

Comment: can you link me to some resources to understand how to build your solution? Thanks and sorry for my bad question

Comment: (i) read package documentation (is part of your LaTeX  installation), (ii) see question and their answer tagged by `forest` (iii) ups, now I see that I forgot to append my code ... (will be corrected asap), whis s far haven't bended arrows ad edges. Are they really needed. Instread them you may consider to add arrowheads to edges (with `\edge={semithick, -Straight Barb}`.

Comment: I'm braking my mind on [forest docs](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf) because I need to customize the arrow to draw a path, in particular, I need to add a label, can you help me to understand how I can do this or you can help me to find some useful resurces? I'm not able to customize the \draw declaration

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo, well, documentation is quite demanding ... but don't forget that forest is based on TikZ, so in it you can use TikZ libraries. To further help you, please ask you new question with MWE, which reproduce your problem. In general, how to write labels on edges is explained  in the package documentation on the page 45.

Comment: Yes, thanks I will open a new question because I need to customize the tree with a  couple of labels and I have problems :/